# MySQL PHPMyAdmin Localhost to accept Magic Quotes

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, magic-quotes

I'm having a small problem with my localhost on Ubuntu to accept data posted with apostrophes from a PHP file into the MySQL database.

Example:

```
It's your birthday!
```

Will not be accepted by my localhost database and it won't accept anything coming with it either.

Example:

```
Its your birthday!
```

Will be accepted by my localhost database and everything else coming with it as long as there's no apostrophes posted.

How can I get my local machine to act like my server online that accepts apostrophes with the data posted to the database? This will be more ensuring to me that my code works while developing.

I want to make my localhost like my servers that accepts the data without using mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Remember, PHP is a completely different language from SQL, with different syntax, metacharacters, etc... Just because PHP can handle an embedded single doesn't mean SQL will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape the string before inserting it to database using the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function see it's docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

**Update:** you should put the magic_quotes_gpc to 'on' in your php.ini file this will make the server escape special characters by adding \  before them just like the `addslashes()` PHP function but I recommend to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function because it makes the mysql escape the string and it's better than the add slashes function or you can use a function like this function I use to do this :

```
function mysql_prep($value) {
  $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
  $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" );
        // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
  if( $new_enough_php )  // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
  {
            // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
    if( $magic_quotes_active ) 
    { 
     $value = stripslashes( $value );
    }
     $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
  } else // before PHP v4.3.0
     { 
      // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
         if( !$magic_quotes_active ) 
         { 
         $value = addslashes( $value ); 
         }
    // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
      }
  return $value;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the best solution like before.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make my localhost like my servers that accepts the data without using mysql_real_escape_string().

You should do it the other way around. Magic quotes are deprecated and being removed entirely in PHP6, because it was a Bad Idea™. As the manual says, "Relying on this feature is **highly discouraged**.".